Install packages through command in ubuntu vm
In my Vm's agent i have already configured openssl, libsoup2.4, glibc etc i want to update to new or some particular version how to upgrade or update the version in ubuntu vm.
i tried below approaches but it not helping. how to update packages  . I need a unique approach to install the packages


$ sudo su
# cd /usr/src
# wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-3.0.2.tar.gz
# tar zxvf openssl-3.0.2.tar.gz
# cd openssl-3.0.2
# ./Configure
# make
# make install




and to update the git version i followed below approaches and that worked



sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:git-core/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git -y




"it not working" is not a good question. Try reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
